# What do I need to to do for Jest to parse an .hbs file?

Tags: jestjs

It seems that Istanbul is trying to parse all the files that were in some way touched by the files imported in the tests. What can I do to stop this?

[A snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRIRz.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Hi @gunr2171! I've updated the description. I was expecting the test to pass.